# How to select a value from an array in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using MongoDb version 3.2.7

I have a mongoose schema like this which has an array of stock in branch schema. I want to select a `subCategoryId` in stock array and get the `currentPrice` of that `subCategoryId` only, for that I am using query

```
var getCriteria = { "stock.subCategoryId": subCategoryId }
var update = { "stock.$.currentPrice": currentPrice }
```

This query works for me at the time of updating the value as I am able to update the `currentPrice` of selected `subCategoryId` perfectly. But when I want to get a price of particular `subCategoryId` the following query gets me all the stocks in the branch collection. The query I am using is this:

```
var getCriteria ={ "stock.subCategoryId": subCategoryId }
```

**Mongoose Schema**

```
var branch = new Schema({
    branchName: { type: String, trim: true, index: true, default: null },
    isBlocked: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
    email: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
    password: { type: String, required:true },
    accessToken: { type: String, trim: true, index: true, unique: true, sparse: true },
    stock: [stock],
});

var stock = new Schema({
    categoryId: { type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: "categoies", default: null },
    subCategoryId: { type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: "subCategories", default: null },
    currentPrice: { type: Number },
    isBlocked: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
    Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true }
});
```

Comment: are you storing whole `stock` document in your `stock` field (`stock : [stock]`)? Why dont you use `references`, and find using `mongoose-populate`?

Comment: @ravishankar yes this is a valuable suggestion but if possible can you just let me know how can I do it this way.
Thank You

Comment: `var update = { "stock.$.subCategoryId": currentPrice }` : it should be `currentPrice` instead of `subCategoryId`. Is that a typo?

Comment: actually it was a typo but this part what i wanted to to was to select a particular subCategoryId and update its current part  
'var update = { "stock.$.currentPrice": currentPrice }'
This part works perfectly fine but when i am just tying to get the value like suppose i want to get currentPrice and categoryId of the particular subCategory I am unable to get that value instead i am getting complete **stock** array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve only the matching array element try this:

```
branch.find(getCriteria,{'stock.$' : 1},function(err,branch){...});
```

`stock.$` will help you to retrieve only the matched element from the array.

Comment: Thank You sir. This works perfectly for me, this is what I wanted.Thank you for your time.

Comment: If it works for you please accept the answer by clicking right tick. So that it doesnt show up in unanswered.

Comment: yes i have tried it but due to less reputation in stackoverflow it wont allow me to do that if you can just accept my question that will help me to reach at that reputation to accept this answer.

Comment: you cannot upvote the answer, but you can accept the answer. There is a right tick below the upvote/ downvote button, Just click that.

Comment: sir can you please tell me this like in above example I was successfully able to get the specific result by using 
**branch.find({"stock.subCategoryId":ObjectId("123")},{'stock.$' : 1},function(err,branch){...});**

Now If in want to apply multiple conditions in same query how can i do that
I have tried this query but this fetch the 1st data that matches the subCategoryId
**branch.find({"stock.subCategoryId":ObjectId("123"),"stock.isBlocked":false},{'stock.$' : 1},function(err,branch){...});**